# Create usercontrol at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a situation where user can change the order of controls on a canvas. Then it will be populated with data and many instances will be placed on a flow document. What will be the right approuch to get it. I was thinking that after changes I should create a usercontrol dynamically and then placed the many instances on the flow document. But I dont know how to create a user control dynamically. Please help.

Comment: What kind of control? Have you tried declaring these controls in the C# 'code-behind' and adding to a canvas/stackpanel etc. yet?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing to me, what are you trying to achieve?  What kind of controls are you trying to create in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Every control in WPF is still an instance of a class. Let's say your user conrol type is  `SuperControl`. Then in order to create it from code you do:

```
var u1 = new SuperControl(); //create a control's instance

u1.Height = 100; //Optionally assign properties to 
u1.Width = 100;  //configure the control

mainGrid.Children.Add(u1); //Place it on a layout element.
```

Comment: I dont have any usercontrol build before hand. Can I use this method to conver a canvas to a usercontrol?

Comment: You can create anew class, that inherits from Canvas and do customization you need. Lets say you call it MyModifiedCanvas. Then you can create an instance of it and place on a layout element like shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. how to place the control at certain position in parent canvas control.